# What C++ data structure is this referring to?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I stumbled upon this code online and wanted to confirm what this data structure is

```
unordered_map<int, int> pre[10];
int main()
{
...
    pre[1] = {{9, 5}, {7, 4}, {3, 2}};
...
}
```

It looks like
`unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> pre` to me. But, I am not sure how  `unordered_map<int, int>` is working in this case. Can someone please explain what this is?

Answer (score 3):

```
unordered_map<int, int> pre[10];
```

Don't forget about the `[10]` at the end. This is an *array* of ten `unordered_map<int, int>` instances. The `main` line is assigning a particular `unordered_map<int, int>` to the one at position `1`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not consider the array part. Thank you for pointing this out to me. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment

```
pre[1] = {{9, 5}, {7, 4}, {3, 2}};
```

is basically equivalent to

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> temporary_map = {{9, 5}, {7, 4}, {3, 2}};
pre[1] = temporary_map;
```

And remember that `pre` is an *array* of ten elements. `pre[1]` is the second element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like `unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, int>> pre` to me.

Indeed it does, except there is `[10]` after it. This makes the variable an array.

> But, I am not sure how `unordered_map<int, int>` is working in this case.

`unordered_map<int, int>` is the type of the elements of the array.